# Php import_request_variable stopped working

Tags: php

Hey everyone I was getting the following error on my web page:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function import_request_variables() in /demo/conn.php on line 5
```

That line is :

```
import_request_variables('gp');
```

I removed that line and received the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function session_register() in /demo/verify.php on line 4
```

That line is:

```
session_register("userName");
```

I removed that line and everything appears to be working fine now. Can anyone tell me what was happening with those 2 lines and if I should replace them with anything or should I just continue on without them.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Refer to the PHP docs - http://uk3.php.net/session_register and http://uk3.php.net/import_request_variables.

Answer (score 9):

I had this problem from before, the work around that i did to fix it i replaced code before with code after that I've written below, so don't use import_request_variables it is deprecated in PHP 5.3 and in PHP 5.4 is removed as it is described in here https://www.php.net/import_request_variables, the following is the fix for the problem that i had:

Code Before:

```
import_request_variables('p');
```

Code After (Replaced the code above with the code below):

```
extract($_GET, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, 'p');
extract($_POST, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, 'p');
```

Comment: Thanks - its nice copy&paste :)

Comment: [**Warning:** Do not use extract() on untrusted data, like user input (e.g. $_GET, $_FILES).](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)

Answer (score 6):

I wrote this replacement. It works for me. I hope it helps you.
 for example this URL : test.php?z=1

```
import_request_variables("gp",'abc_');
echo $abc_z; // 1
function import_request_variables($g,$prfix)
{
    foreach($_GET as $k => $v)
    {
        $v_name = $prfix.$k;
        global $$v_name;
        ${$prfix.$k} = $v;
    }
    foreach($_POST as $k => $v)
    {
        $v_name = $prfix.$k;
        global $$v_name;
        ${$prfix.$k} = $v;
    }
}
```