# Fatal error: Call to undefined function import_request_variables()

Tags: php, post, echo

I get this error when run Result.php

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function import_request_variables()

**Result.php**

```
   <HTML>
    <HEAD>
    <TITLE> This Result.php </TITLE>
    <?php
    import_request_variables("p","f_");
    ?>
    </HEAD> 
    <body>
    <?php
    if($f_uname=="Ali" && $f_pass=="123")
    {
        echo ("Welcome <br/>\n");
    }   
    else
    {
        echo ("Invalid Username & Password!!");
    }
    ?>  
    </body>
    </HTML>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36972088/4248328

Comment: extract($_POST,EXTR_PREFIX_ALL,f); is correct ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to `php.net`

> Warning
>   This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.