# What is the correct (safe) alternative to PHP import_request_variables?

Tags: php

Full disclosure: I'm not a PHP programmer, rather a Javascript/Node programmer, but I'm trying to help a friend fix a fatal PHP error on their site.

To wit,

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function import_request_variables()
```

I've looked it up and `import_request_variables()` is deprecated.

The relevant piece of code is this -- I noticed that the developer seems to have tried out the more modern form (?) and abandoned it.

```
import_request_variables("pgc", "re_");
//extract($_GET, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "pgc");
//extract($_POST, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "pgc");
//extract($_GET, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "re_");
//extract($_POST, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, "re_");
```

I found a solution on Stack Overflow here [Php import_request_variable stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24782633/php-import-request-variable-stopped-working), that suggests using that same extract method

```
extract($_GET, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, 'p');
extract($_POST, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, 'p');
```

Is this the correct method to follow?  I've read in other posts (e.g. [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=import_request_variables%20not%20working&oq=import_request_variables%20not%20working&aqs=chrome..69i57.3071j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8))  that this could lead to security errors, as does the PHP documentation [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)

```
Warning
Do not use extract() on untrusted data, like user input (e.g. $_GET, $_FILES).
```

and that it's best to import the variables specifically, but I'm not sure that I'm adept enough at PHP to go through all the code and figure out where each variable is being used...

What's the best way to solve this issue swiftly and securely?

Thanks for any help!

EDIT:

This is the code where the variables are used, for what it's worth

```
if ($re_sub && $re_sec) { $content="./$re_sec/$re_sub.php";}
else if ($re_sec)    { $content="./$re_sec/index.php";}
else              { $content="./home.php";}
```

Comment: I'd say - if the first thing you do in your code is `extract` then that's okay. If you do it somewhere in the middle it could overwrite some of your variables. 

But this one is also cool if you use a never php version: https://3v4l.org/ataYn

Comment: Thanks -- @kuh-chan, but is it safe to use it with GET?

Comment: Here is an example where the `extract` can be a security issue: https://3v4l.org/UpIvt If the `extract` is done in the first line there won't be any issues as `$sum` would be overwritten with the database value. If you used the syntax I proposed you'd have full control over the variables being imported

Comment: I think the more important question is why do you want to create variables out of POST/GET data? You already have that data populated in superglobals, why not use them as it is?

Comment: @Dharman -- I'm trying to fix code left a long time ago by another developer.  I'm not sure what he's doing other than grab query params -- `content.php?sec=films` for instance -- and then use that to load different content (see my edit above in the main post).  I tried using `extract`, but uncommenting his code, but I get nothing for `$re_sub` and `$re_sec`.  Is there another approach you'd recommend for grabbing this variables ?

Comment: This is an example of the PHP code you should not write. I am sorry, but the best advice I can give your friend is to start over. The code in your edit is unmaintainable and could be a security risk.

Answer (score 2):

Wow. `import_request_variables` went away in PHP5, that was a LONG time ago... hope you are upgrading to 7!

Anyway, it seems that you are basically trying to form POST and the content of the post determine the URL the user is sent to. Since you can't trust user input (or shouldn't anyway) you check what is sent in the $_POST array against a whitelist.  Depending on how many sections and sub-sections you have, that whitelist can be hard coded, kept in a separate include file, stored in a database, etc.

Given a structure like

```
home
  sec1
    sec1sub1
    sec1sub2
    sec1sub3
  sec2
    sec2sub1
    sec2sub2
    sec2sub3
  sec3
    sec3sub1
    sec3sub2
    sec3sub3
```

You can do something like loop through your whitelist and see if a matching POST variable was sent, if so add it to the URL.

```
$url="/";
$whitelist=array();
$whitelist['cars']=array("compact","sedan","sportscar");
$whitelist['trucks']=array("diesel","4x4");
$whitelist['suvs']=array("crossovers","domestic","import");

foreach($whitelist as $k=>$v){
  if(isset($_POST[$k])){
    $url=$url."/".$k;
    foreach($v as $subv){
       if(isset($_POST[$subv])){
          $url=$url."/".$subv;
       }
    }
  }
}
header("location :".$url);
```